# Stop UISheetPresentationController from resizing in smaller detents

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

I am using a `UISheetPresentationController` with two custom detents - a smaller and larger detent. In the viewController that presents the sheet, here is the setup:

```
    let viewControllerToPresent = PresentedViewController()
    if let sheet = viewControllerToPresent.sheetPresentationController {
      let identifier =
      UISheetPresentationController.Detent.Identifier("Identifier")
      sheet.detents = [.custom(identifier: identifier) { _ in 20 }, .custom { _ in 700 }]
      sheet.largestUndimmedDetentIdentifier = identifier
      sheet.preferredCornerRadius = 30
    }
    navigationController?.present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: true)
```

Here is the code for the presented sheet:

```
class PresentedViewController: UIHostingController<PresentedView> {
  init() {
    super.init(rootView: PresentedView())
  }
  
  @MainActor required dynamic init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
  
}

struct PresentedView: View {
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("Title")
        .padding(.top, 30)
        .padding(.bottom, 10)
      ScrollView {
          RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 14)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 100, alignment: .center)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The issue I'm having is that the padding of the "Title" on the sheet isn't consistent, ie when the sheet is in the smaller detent, the top padding of the title is much smaller than 30 px, whereas when the sheet is moved up to the larger detent, the padding  is 30 px. Is there a way to keep this padding amount consistent between detent sizes, instead of having it dynamically resized?

Images:

**Shorter detent -**

[image: Image1]

**Larger detent -**

[image: Image2]

Comment: That is the main difference between SwiftUI and UIKit. SwiftUI adapts to multiple screens and sizes, this is by design. You can use .frame to fix the size of something but you have to control that variable in all scenarios. Padding is more of a suggestion/ideal but SwiftUI is not bound by it.

Comment: Thank you for the advice @loremipsum! After some experimentation, what seems to work is wrapping the whole PresentedView in a ScrollView and disabling scrolling to mainain the desired padding.